# Prove Jensen's inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, jensen-inequality

I was interested to see a proof for Jensen's inequality for the following variant:

Let $X$ be a **discrete** random variable with finite expected value and let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. then:
$h(E[X])\leq E[h(X)]$

Please note, I'm interested in a proof for this variant with a **discrete** random variable. The proof in Wikipedia doesn't match my needs.

Comment: I suppose it could be extrapolated from the idea used in this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382006/could-someone-give-a-detailed-yet-elementary-proof-for-jensens-inequality/4019537#4019537

Comment: You are free to ask a proof different from the one in Wikipedia, but that proof also applies to the discrete case

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez wikipedia doesn't have proof for ℎ([])≤[ℎ()] for infinite case

Comment: @David yes, it does. Look at the "measure theoretical proof" and take $\mu$ to be the adecuate measure for the infinite case. I cannot help you if you don't know why measures generalize discrete and continuous probabilities

Comment: they proved it on finite n, still this is not what I asked about @AitorIribarLopez

Comment: Some hints: (1) it is sufficient to check the inequality in the case when $E[X]=0$ and when $h(0)=0$ (why?); (2) since $h$ is convex there is a real $c$ such that $h(x)\ge cx$ (why?); (3) taking expected values preserves inequalities.

Comment: @David no, I am not talking about that proof, I am talking about Proof 2 (measure-theoretical form). You should honestly think about it since it appears to me that you have a fixated idea in your head and won't listen to my advices

Answer (score 2):

I believe you might be interested in the proof provided in Theorem 2.4 in *Probability and Computing: Randomization and Probabilistic Techniques in Algorithms and data Analysis, Second Edition* from M. Mitzenmacher and E. Upfal. The only assumption there is that $f$ has a Taylor expansion, so your random variable can be either discrete or continuous.

> Let $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$. By Taylor's theorem there is a value $c$ such that
> \begin{align}
> f(x) &= f(\mu) + f^\prime(\mu)(x-\mu) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(c)(x-\mu)^2}{2}\\&\geq f(\mu) + f^\prime(\mu)(x-\mu),
> \end{align}
> since $f^{\prime\prime}(c) > 0$. Taking expectations of both sides and applying linearity of expectations and Lemma 2.2 yields the result:
> \begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}[f(x)] &\geq \mathbb{E}[f(\mu) + f^\prime(\mu)(x-\mu)]
> \\&= \mathbb{E}[f(\mu)] + f^\prime(\mu)\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu)]
> \\&= f(\mu) = f(\mathbb{E}[X])
> \end{align}

Comment: You proof assumes that $f$ is of class $\mathcal C^2$, which is not necessary. To fix it, you can use that for a convex function and a point$x_0$ ($x_0=\mu$ in this case) there are $a$, $b$ such that $f(x) \geq ax+b$ with equality at $x=x_0$ ie there exists a "subtangent line". Also, for the OP, note that this proof applies wether $X$ is finite, countable, continuous or whatever you want