# Expectation of transformed mean of multiple random variables <= mean of the expectation of their transformation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I am trying to understand the following. If $M$ is the number of different random variables $X_1 ... X_M$, are there any conditions under which we can claim that:

$$E\left[f(\sum_{m=1}^M w_m X_m)\right] \leq \sum_{m=1}^M w_mE[f(X_m)]$$

So far, I think that it suffices for $f$ to be convex and for all $w_m$  to be non-negative with $\sum_{m=1}^M w_m = 1$. Because then, if we treat $E[f(.)]$ as itself a function, then [this Jensen's formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382006/could-someone-give-a-detailed-yet-elementary-proof-for-jensens-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1) applies. However:

- I am not sure this is a reasonable interpretation to make when applying Jensen inequality to random variables
- if not, are there other conditions (for ex. bounds on the random variables or characteristics of $f$) that would make the inequality to hold?

Answer (score 1):

Jensen inequality can be relevant here, but not wrt your expectation (because Jensen is about taking the expectation inside-outside the function, which is not the case here).

If we instead leave the expectation aside, then, if $f$ is convex and  $w_m \ge 0$, letting $W=\sum w_w$, and we can indeed apply [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) (again, ignoring that $X_m$ are random variables) :

$$f \left(\frac{1}{W} \sum w_m X_m\right) \le \frac{1}{W}  \sum w_m f(X_m)$$

In particular, if $W=1$:

$$f \left(\ \sum w_m X_m\right) \le   \sum w_m f(X_m)$$

Taking expectations on both sides you get your inequality.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. When you say "ignoring that $X_m$ are random variables" do you mean that just as a strategy to proceed with the proof (since in the end we take the expectations on both sides to recover the original formulae) or do you mean that the original inequality will only hold for constants?

Comment: @ZXiu it means that inequality holds always.